# When I add products to one user's shopping cart, those same products are removed from another user's shopping cart. How is this possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've looked through my code and I can't understand why this is happening.

I create a cookie/guid for guest users in the pipeline using custom middleware if a) user is not authenticated and cookie does not exist.

Like this:

```
 public class GuestCookieMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public GuestCookieMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            string? userName = null;

            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("guest")) // If guest has a cookie
                {
                    userName = context.Request.Cookies["guest"];
                }

                if (!Guid.TryParse(userName, out var _))
                {
                    userName = null;
                }
            }
            
            if (userName == null)
            {
                userName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions { IsEssential = true, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) };
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("guest", userName, cookieOptions);
            }

            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

```
public static class GuestCookieMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseGuestCookie(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<GuestCookieMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Then, when I press Cart on the website, it goes through this controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString() : Request.Cookies["guest"];
  
            IndexViewModel vm = new IndexViewModel
            {
                UserCart = await _cartServices.GetOrCreateCart(userId)
            };

            return View(vm);
        }
```

And the entire CartService class looks like this:

```
public async Task<ShoppingCartDto> GetOrCreateCart(string? userId)
        {
            var cart = await _context.ShoppingCarts
                .Include(x => x.Products).ThenInclude(x => x.Brand)
                .Include(x => x.Products).ThenInclude(x => x.ProductType).ThenInclude(x => x.Category)
                .Where(x => x.BuyerId == userId).Select(x => new ShoppingCartDto(x))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();


            if (cart == null)
            {
                return await CreateCartForUser(userId);
            }

            return cart;
        }

        public async Task<ShoppingCartDto> CreateCartForUser(string? userId)
        {
            var cart = new ShoppingCart(userId);

            _context.ShoppingCarts.Add(cart);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return await _context.ShoppingCarts.Where(x => x.BuyerId == userId).Select(x => new ShoppingCartDto(x)).FirstAsync();
        }
        
        // Add quantity and price too parameters?
        public async Task AddToCart(string? userId, int productId, int cartId)
        {
            var cart = await _context.ShoppingCarts.Where(x => x.BuyerId == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if(cart == null)
            {
                cart = new ShoppingCart(userId);
                _context.ShoppingCarts.Add(cart);
            }

            // FirstAsync since we know the product should always exist. 
            cart.Products.Add(await _context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == productId).FirstAsync());

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And the add product action looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(int productId)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString() : Request.Cookies["guest"];

            var cart = await _cartServices.GetOrCreateCart(userId);

            await _cartServices.AddToCart(userId, productId, cart.Id);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Catalog");
        }
```

Where is the problem occuring? I've tried stepping through the program multiple times. I don't understand why it happens.

Everything works fine except for adding products, during which products from the other cart are removed.

When I add products to a cart and I stay logged in on that account, they are successfully persisted through every request. I can add products and I can check cart. When I re-log, the cart is intact. But when I add products to another cart, they disappear from that cart.

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag.

Comment: Are all the accounts you logged in all  guest users? From your code, The information of  Cart and products are all saved in database, I don't think when you use another account to add product into cart, The db will delete the previous account information.